# How to combine/convert 3 SAS queries into 1 SQL statement to execute in R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I currently have an R program that pulls data from a warehouse and creates a set of reports. The data querying uses the RODBC library in R and I currently have just the following query code

```
manifest_query <- "
  select
    bkg.syn_sail_key,
    bkg.sail_ship_cd,
    bkg.sail_sail_dte,
    bkg.sail_dura_days,
    bkg.book_num,
    bkg.pax_seq_num,
    bkg.rdate,
    bkg.cabin,
    bkg.cabin_book_num,
    bkg.meta_category_code,
    bkg.rate_code,
    bkg.person_num,
    bkg.rdate,
    person.past_guest_num,
    person.first_name,
    person.last_name,
    person.gender,
    person.date_of_birth,
    person.tier_code
  from
    dw.bkg_contact_fact bkg
    inner join dw_crm.person_dim person
    on person.person_num = bkg.person_num
  where
    bkg.cancelled_pax_ind = 'N' and
    bkg.sail_sail_dte >= to_date('%start_date%', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
    bkg.sail_sail_dte <= to_date('%end_date%', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  "
```

I need to add 3 more columns to this output table from 2 additional queries that I have executed in the SAS code below. The first one actually only adds a MIN computed column to the result from the above query

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK."NEXT_SAIL"n AS 
   SELECT t1.SYN_SAIL_KEY, 
          t1.SAIL_DURA_DAYS, 
          t1.SAIL_SAIL_DTE, 
          t1.SAIL_SHIP_CD, 
          t1.RDATE, 
          t1.CABIN_BOOK_NUM, 
          t1.BOOK_NUM, 
          t1.PAX_SEQ_NUM, 
          t1.CABIN, 
          t1.RATE_CODE, 
          t1.PERSON_NUM, 
          t1.FIRST_NAME, 
          t1.LAST_NAME, 
          t1.PAST_GUEST_NUM, 
          t1.GENDER, 
          t1.DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
          t1.TIER_CODE, 
          /* MIN_of_SAIL_SAIL_DTE */
            (MIN(t2.SAIL_SAIL_DTE)) FORMAT=DATETIME20. AS MIN_of_SAIL_SAIL_DTE
      FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_BKG_CONTACT_FACT t1
           LEFT JOIN DW.BKG_CONTACT_FACT t2 ON (t1.PERSON_NUM = t2.PERSON_NUM) AND (t1.SAIL_SAIL_DTE < t2.SAIL_SAIL_DTE)
      GROUP BY t1.SYN_SAIL_KEY,
               t1.SAIL_DURA_DAYS,
               t1.SAIL_SAIL_DTE,
               t1.SAIL_SHIP_CD,
               t1.RDATE,
               t1.CABIN_BOOK_NUM,
               t1.BOOK_NUM,
               t1.PAX_SEQ_NUM,
               t1.CABIN,
               t1.RATE_CODE,
               t1.PERSON_NUM,
               t1.FIRST_NAME,
               t1.LAST_NAME,
               t1.PAST_GUEST_NUM,
               t1.GENDER,
               t1.DATE_OF_BIRTH
      ORDER BY t1.SAIL_SAIL_DTE;
QUIT;
```

And the final one adds the two final columns but the 'PAX_CANCEL...' must be included as a join criterion

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_NEXT_SAIL_0002 AS 
   SELECT t1.SYN_SAIL_KEY, 
          t1.SAIL_DURA_DAYS, 
          t1.SAIL_SAIL_DTE, 
          t1.SAIL_SHIP_CD, 
          t1.RDATE, 
          t1.CABIN_BOOK_NUM, 
          t1.BOOK_NUM, 
          t1.PAX_SEQ_NUM, 
          t1.CABIN, 
          t1.RATE_CODE, 
          t1.PERSON_NUM, 
          t1.FIRST_NAME, 
          t1.LAST_NAME, 
          t1.PAST_GUEST_NUM, 
          t1.GENDER, 
          t1.DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
          t1.MIN_of_SAIL_SAIL_DTE, 
          t2.SAIL_SHIP_CD AS SAIL_SHIP_CD1, 
          t2.RATE_CODE AS RATE_CODE1
      FROM WORK.NEXT_SAIL t1
           LEFT JOIN DW.BKG_CONTACT_FACT t2 ON (t1.PERSON_NUM = t2.PERSON_NUM) AND (t1.MIN_of_SAIL_SAIL_DTE = 
          t2.SAIL_SAIL_DTE AND (t2.PAX_CANCEL_DTE IS MISSING ));
QUIT;
```

Its easy to do these in SAS as the process flow lets you use 'work' tables easily but my questions are:

- How do I convert the SAS queries to correct SQL syntax that R will read?
- In that code, can I nest the queries into one block statement so I only need to run the query command once?
- or how do I execute several queries to get the same table result that I am getting in SAS?

Comment: You may use `library(sqldf)` with similar syntax as in proc sql.

Comment: Does your first SAS SQL code generate a warning about remerging statistics? If so, it won't translate directly to R.

Comment: No, there are no errors. The code currently runs and the outputs are generated perfectly. That first snippet is pulled straight out of the working R code. And the SAS queries both execute. I haven't combined them as I am unaware how to successfully do so, but in their own environment everything works

Comment: The text given to R is simply passed along to the SQL-server. What happens if you just wrap double quotes around the SQL code in the SAS Proc?